# How to generate html reports using Scalatest?

Tags: scala, reporting, scalatest

New Scala and Scalatest user.

I've written some tests using the Scalatest library and I've run it. How can I get a dump of the test report in an html (or some other) format?

thx.

Answer (score 1):

For an html Report, you'd use -h  for Runner or sbt:

http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-2.0.RC1/#org.scalatest.tools.Runner$

An HTML report requires ScalaTest 2.0. If you are using the Ant task or Maven plugin, there's special syntax for it as well. How are you running your tests?

Comment: Thanks. I am using the Eclipse plugin. Where can I specify the Runner parameters?

Scala IDE for Eclipse 3.0.1.v-2_10-201307110731-b1c1861
ScalaTest for Scala IDE 2.9.3.v-3-2_10-201309130846-55f5c32

Comment: Bill - the link you posted got stale. I think the documentation you wrote (that i ref'd in my answer)  provides the correct answer.  Scalatest is a great tool.. thank you for contributing it.   /chris

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the reports this configuration stanza did the trick for me:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
    <filereports>TestSuite.txt</filereports>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
```

Please see:  http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin